# What are all entire functions that satisfies $|f(z)| \leq 2|z|^2 + 1$

Tags: complex-analysis

What are all entire functions that satisfies $|f(z)| \leq 2|z|^2 + 1$

I’m thinking of using Taylor’s Theorem and Cauchy Inequality to solve this, however I still don’t know where to start in order to extract the entire functions.

Help please? Thanks!

Comment: Cauchy's inequalities easily show that $f$ must be a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: Use Cauchy integral formula for derivative on a circle with arbitrary radius R. Then, as R$\to \infty$, you can get taylor coefficients are 0 for $n\ge3$.